# How can I send a file with the POST method from C# to a PHP file which (PHP) gets files from a HTML form by the '$_FILES' function?

Tags: c#, php, post

#### First

I have a [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) file that gets data and file from a HTML form and uploads a file to a specific directory by the `$_POST` and `$_FILES` methods.

#### Second

I have Windows aplication ([C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29)). The user can drag and drop any file to a listview. I send the user's data to a PHP file by the POST method and it (the PHP file) upadtes the database. My problem is I won't to send file in listview drag and dropped by the user to the PHP file as it could get the file by the `$_FILES` method and access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to POST a single file from C# to your PHP script you could use the [UploadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esst63h0.aspx) method:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.UploadFile("http://example.com/script.php", "POST", @"C:\path\test.txt");
}
```

If along with the file you want to send some other data and/or multiple files you will need to forge a `multipart/form-data` request manually. Here's a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data) explaining how to achieve this.

Comment: Mr Dimitrov I do what you said As Below

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.UploadFile("http://K45/j/_dokuman/Dokuman/Islem22.php", "POST", @"C:\test.txt");
}

Comment: MY "Islem22.php" is like this.But it didnt upload the file to specified directory

$filename = $_FILES['DosyaAdi']['name']; 

$temp = explode('.',$filename);
$temp = array_reverse($temp);
$Uzanti = $temp[0];


  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['DosyaAdi']['tmp_name'], "C://www/wamp/j")) {

   alert( basename( $_FILES['DosyaAdi']['name'])." dosyası başarıyla yüklendi");
    }

Comment: `UploadFile` uses `file` as name. Try with `$_FILES['file']['name']`. If you want more control over this you may take a look at this article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/uploadfileex.aspx?display=Print

Comment: Thanx Dimitrov.I use $_FILES['file']['name'] file instead of DosyaAdi then everything become Right .Thanks alot

Answer (score -3):

Learn the HTTP protocol and pray for the site owner not banning the user's IP address for the terms-of-use violation.

Comment: My problem is I dont know how to send file by POST method from c# side

Comment: Rude, and pointless response. He specifically asked for help in sending it through C#, but yet you feel the need to be cruel. LAME.